# How to Sort Table Columns PHP, MySQL, javaScript AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, crud

This is a code portion of a CRUD that allows me to create, read, update and delete with no refresh page using AJAX, PHP, MySQL and JavaScript. I would like to know if is there any way to sort the results with no refresh page when clicking on the `th` of the `thead` column using AJAX?

index.php

```
include 'inc/funciones/funciones.php';
<table id="listado-contactos" class="listado-contactos">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Empresa</th>
            <th>Teléfono</th>
            <th>Acciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php $contactos = obtenerContactos();
        if ($contactos->num_rows) :
            foreach ($contactos as $contacto) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $contacto['nombre']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $contacto['empresa']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $contacto['telefono']; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="editar.php?id=<?php echo $contacto['id_contacto']; ?>" class="btn btn-editar">
                            <i class="fas fa-pen-square"></i>
                        </a>
                        <button data-id="<?php echo $contacto['id_contacto']; ?>" type="button" class="btn btn-borrar">
                            <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

db.php

```
<?php
define('DB_USUARIO', 'root');
define('DB_PASWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NOMBRE', 'agendaphp');
define('DB_PORT', '3306');

$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USUARIO, DB_PASWORD, DB_NOMBRE, DB_PORT);
// echo $conn->ping();
?>
```

funciones.php

```
<?php
function obtenerContactos() {
    include 'db.php';
    try {
        return $conn->query("SELECT id_contacto, nombre, empresa, telefono FROM contactos");

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "error" . $e->getMessage() . "<br>";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, using a plugin like this [jQuery TableSorter](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/)

Comment: Hi Jay, I just implemented the plugin you sugested me and it works, it's very easy to use, thank you very much for answering. But now i would like to know if is there any way to sort the results using mysql (ORDER by ASC). i explain me, first the results sohw in the table with the order from the database, after clicking on the th of the thead column call again to the database and with no page refresh show the result in ASC order using ajax i think...

Comment: You mean clicking on the column header and making an AJAX request to MySQL with a different sort? If so, that would be a lot of work.

Comment: Yes i mean that, i know is more complex but also more elegant solution. may be the problem is that i don't have the knowledge yet. I have to study more. Even so I have shared all the code of my project in case you see a possible solution.

Comment: What makes it more elegant? The jQuery solution is very elegant and doesn't require more round trips to the database which tend to be the largest resource hogs in web design.

Comment: Sorry I really don't know what I say. You're right, I'll finally use your proposal. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

by Ajax method you can request a server to get data from that: as Ajax is a javascript code you need js code and after that, you need call PHP server code with your ajax so that you need the PHP file code also, so PHP code communicate with database for you and return data to your javascript file.
so first we will create a PHP file to be ready for ajax:

server.php :

```
<?php 
$db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pass","db_name");
$u_sent_from_ajax = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['sendAnythingToPhp']); //20

    $select_query = "SELECT * FROM your_table";
$data_query = $db->query($select_query);
if ($data_query ->num_rows > 0) {
  
    $i=0;
    while($row = $data_query->fetch_assoc()) { // march the row array
       $result_array[$i]= $row;
       
          $i=$i+1;
    }
}
mysqli_close($db);

echo json_encode($result_array); // it sends $result_array to ajax request as a data
  ?>
```

now: your request file on client-side -> ajax.js:

```
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'sendMe.php',                  //the script to call to get data   
        
      sendAnythingToPhp: "20",      //you can send  your desire value to server also and then get there and use
      //sendAnythingToPhp_1: "21",    
        
      dataType: 'json',                //data format    JSON  
      success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
      {

 console.log(data); // use your retured data from above php code to your html file
          
    });
```

Comment: you need work step by step, firstly you need to have data in your hand then sort and use click events to reach your desire. it should be done gradually.

Comment: Do not use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

Comment: Hi Fernand, thank you very much for answering. I don't have the knowledge to implement your answer in my code. I paste all the code from my project so maybe you can give me a more specific answer related to my project.

Answer (score 0):

The complete code except css files:

header.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="es-ES">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Agenda de Contactos</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <meta property="og:title" content="">
    <meta property="og:type" content="">
    <meta property="og:url" content="">
    <meta property="og:image" content="">

    <link rel="manifest" href="site.webmanifest">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" sizes="16x16">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontawesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

    <meta name="theme-color" content="#fafafa">
</head>

<body>
```

footer.php

```
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-3.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    <script>
        window.ga = function() {
            ga.q.push(arguments)
        };
        ga.q = [];
        ga.l = +new Date;
        ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
        ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);
        ga('set', 'transport', 'beacon');
        ga('send', 'pageview')
    </script>
    <script src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js" async></script>
</body>

</html>
```

index.php

```
<?php
include 'inc/funciones/funciones.php';
include 'inc/layout/header.php';
?>

<div class="contenedor-barra">
    <h1>Agenda de Contactos</h1>
</div>

<div class="contenedor bg-amarillo sombra">
    <form action="#" id="contacto">
        <legend>Añada un contacto <span>Todos los campos son obligatorios</span></legend>
        <?php include 'inc/layout/formulario.php'; ?>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="contenedor bg-blanco sombra contactos">
    <div class="contenedor-contactos">
        <h2>Contactos</h2>
        <input type="text" id="buscar" class="buscador sombra" placeholder="Buscar contactos...">
        <p class="total-contactos"><span></span> Contactos</p>
        <div class="contenedor-tabla">
            <table id="listado-contactos" class="listado-contactos">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Empresa</th>
                        <th>Teléfono</th>
                        <th>Acciones</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php $contactos = obtenerContactos();
                    if ($contactos->num_rows) :
                        foreach ($contactos as $contacto) : ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $contacto['nombre']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $contacto['empresa']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $contacto['telefono']; ?></td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="editar.php?id=<?php echo $contacto['id_contacto']; ?>" class="btn btn-editar">
                                        <i class="fas fa-pen-square"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <button data-id="<?php echo $contacto['id_contacto']; ?>" type="button" class="btn btn-borrar">
                                        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php include 'inc/layout/footer.php'; ?>
```

editar.php

```
<?php
include 'inc/funciones/funciones.php';
include 'inc/layout/header.php';

$id = filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

if(!$id) {
    die('No es valido');
}

$resultado = obtenerContacto($id);
$contacto = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
?>

<div class="contenedor-barra">
    <div class="contenedor barra">
        <a href="index.php" class="btn volver">Volver</a>
        <h1>Editar Contacto</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="contenedor bg-amarillo sombra">
    <form action="#" id="contacto">
        <legend>Edite el contacto</span></legend>
        <?php include 'inc/layout/formulario.php'; ?>
    </form>
</div>

<?php include 'inc/layout/footer.php'; ?>
```

formulario.php

```
<div class="campos">
    <div class="campo">
        <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
        <input 
            type="text" 
            placeholder="Nombre contacto" 
            id="nombre" 
            value="<?php echo (isset($contacto['nombre'])) ? $contacto['nombre'] : '';?>"
            >
    </div>
    <div class="campo">
        <label for="empresa">Empresa:</label>
        <input 
            type="text" 
            placeholder="Nombre empresa" 
            id="empresa"
            value="<?php echo (isset($contacto['empresa'])) ? $contacto['empresa'] : '';?>"
            >
    </div>
    <div class="campo">
        <label for="telefono">Teléfono:</label>
        <input 
            type="tel" 
            placeholder="Teléfono contacto" 
            id="telefono"
            value="<?php echo (isset($contacto['telefono'])) ? $contacto['telefono'] : ''; ?>"
        >
    </div>
</div>
<div class="boton enviar">
    <?php
    $textoBtn = isset($contacto['telefono']) ? 'Guardar' : 'Añadir';
    $accion = isset($contacto['telefono']) ? 'editar' : 'crear';
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" id ="accion" value="<?php echo $accion; ?>">
    <?php if(isset($contacto['id_contacto'])) {?>
        <input type="hidden" id ="id" value="<?php echo $contacto['id_contacto']; ?>">
    <?php } ?>
    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $textoBtn; ?>">
</div>
```

modelo-contacto.php

```
<?php
if($_POST) {
    if($_POST['accion'] == 'crear') {
        // Creará un nuevo rgistro en la base de datos
        require_once('../funciones/bd.php');
    
        // Validar las entradas
        $nombre = filter_var($_POST['nombre'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $empresa = filter_var($_POST['empresa'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $telefono = filter_var($_POST['telefono'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        
        try {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO contactos (nombre, empresa, telefono) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("sss", $nombre, $empresa, $telefono);
            $stmt->execute();
            if($stmt->affected_rows == 1) {
                $respuesta = array(
                    'respuesta' => 'correcto',
                    'info' => $stmt->affected_rows,                
                    'datos' => array(
                        'id_insertado' => $stmt->insert_id,
                        'nombre' => $nombre,
                        'empresa' => $empresa,
                        'telefono' => $telefono
                    )
                );
            } else {
                $respuesta = array(
                    'respuesta' => 'error'
                );
            }
            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close();
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            $respuesta = array(
                'error' => $e->getMessage()
            );
        }
        echo json_encode($respuesta);
        // echo json_encode($_POST);
    }
}

if ($_GET) {
    if($_GET['accion'] == 'borrar') {
        require_once('../funciones/bd.php');

        $id = filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        try {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM contactos WHERE id_contacto = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
            $stmt->execute();
            if($stmt->affected_rows == 1) {
                $respuesta = array(
                    'respuesta' => 'correcto'
                );
            } else {
                $respuesta = array(
                    'respuesta' => 'error'
                );
            }
            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close();
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            $respuesta = array(
                'error' => $e->getMessage()
            );
        }
        echo json_encode($respuesta);
    }
}

if ($_POST) {
    if($_POST['accion'] == 'editar') {
        // echo json_encode($_POST);

        require_once('../funciones/bd.php');

        // Validar las entradas
        $nombre = filter_var($_POST['nombre'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $empresa = filter_var($_POST['empresa'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $telefono = filter_var($_POST['telefono'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $id = filter_var($_POST['id'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

        try {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE contactos SET nombre = ?, empresa = ?, telefono = ? WHERE id_contacto = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("sssi", $nombre, $empresa, $telefono, $id);
            $stmt->execute();
            if($stmt->affected_rows >= 0) { // En el proyecto original era == 1 pero daba error al no modificar datos
                $respuesta = array(
                    'respuesta' => 'correcto'
                );
            } else {
                $respuesta = array(
                    'respuesta' => 'error'
                );
            }
            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close();
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            $respuesta = array(
                'error' => $e->getMessage()
            );
        }
        echo json_encode($respuesta);
    }
}
?>
```

bd.php

```
<?php

// Credenciales de la base de datos
define('DB_USUARIO', 'root');
define('DB_PASWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NOMBRE', 'agendaphp');
define('DB_PORT', '3306');

$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USUARIO, DB_PASWORD, DB_NOMBRE, DB_PORT);
// echo $conn->ping();

?>
```

funciones.php

```
<?php
function obtenerContactos() {
    include 'bd.php';
    try {
        return $conn->query("SELECT id_contacto, nombre, empresa, telefono FROM contactos ORDER BY nombre ASC");

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "error" . $e->getMessage() . "<br>";
        return false;
    }
}

// Obtiene un contacto y toma un id
function obtenerContacto($id) {
    include 'bd.php';
    try {
        return $conn->query("SELECT id_contacto, nombre, empresa, telefono FROM contactos WHERE id_contacto = $id");

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "error" . $e->getMessage() . "<br>";
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

main.js

```
const formularioContactos = document.querySelector('#contacto'),
      listadoContactos = document.querySelector('#listado-contactos tbody'),
      inputBuscador = document.querySelector('#buscar');

eventListeners();

function eventListeners() {
    // Cuando el formulario de crear o editar se ejecuta
    formularioContactos.addEventListener('submit', leerFormulario);

    // Listener para eliminar el boton
    if(listadoContactos) {
        listadoContactos.addEventListener('click', eliminarContacto);
    }

    // Buscador
    if(inputBuscador) {
        inputBuscador.addEventListener('input', buscarContactos);
    };
    
    numeroContactos();
};

function leerFormulario(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Leer los datos de los inputs
    const nombre = document.querySelector('#nombre').value,
          empresa = document.querySelector('#empresa').value,
          telefono = document.querySelector('#telefono').value,
          accion = document.querySelector('#accion').value;

    if(nombre === '' || empresa === '' || telefono === '') {
        mostrarNotificacion('Todos los campos son obligatorios', 'error');

    } else {
        // Pasa la validación, crear llamado a ajax
        const infoContacto = new FormData();
        infoContacto.append('nombre', nombre);
        infoContacto.append('empresa', empresa);
        infoContacto.append('telefono', telefono);
        infoContacto.append('accion', accion);
        // console.log(...infoContacto); // (...) Spread Operator -> transforma un array en una lista de argumentos
        if(accion === 'crear') {
            // Creamos un nuevo contacto
            insertarBD(infoContacto);
        } else {
            // Editar el contacto
            // Leer el id
            const idRegistro = document.querySelector('#id').value;
            infoContacto.append('id', idRegistro);
            actualizarRegistro(infoContacto);
        };
    }
};

// Inserta en la base de datos via Ajax
function insertarBD(datos) {
    // Llamar a ajax
    // Crear el objeto
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Abrir la conexion
    xhr.open("POST", "inc/modelos/modelo-contacto.php", true);

    // Pasar los datos
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if(this.status === 200) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
            // Leemos la respuesta de PHP
            const respuesta = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            
            // Inserta un nuevo elemento a la tabla
            const nuevoContacto = document.createElement('tr');
            nuevoContacto.innerHTML = `
            <td>${respuesta.datos.nombre}</td>
            <td>${respuesta.datos.empresa}</td>
            <td>${respuesta.datos.telefono}</td>
            `;

            // Crear contenedor para los botones
            const contenedorAcciones = document.createElement('td');
            
            // Crear el icono de editar
            const iconoEditar = document.createElement('i');
            iconoEditar.classList.add('fas', 'fa-pen-square');
            // Crear el enlace para el icono de editar
            const btnEditar = document.createElement('a');
            btnEditar.appendChild(iconoEditar);
            btnEditar.href = `editar.php?id=${respuesta.datos.id_insertado}`;
            btnEditar.classList.add('btn', 'btn-editar');
            // Agregarlo al padre
            contenedorAcciones.appendChild(btnEditar);
            
            // Crear el icono de borrar
            const iconoBorrar = document.createElement('i');
            iconoBorrar.classList.add('fas', 'fa-trash-alt');
            // Crear el boton para el icono de borrar
            const btnBorrar = document.createElement('button');
            btnBorrar.appendChild(iconoBorrar);
            btnBorrar.setAttribute('data-id', respuesta.datos.id_insertado);
            btnBorrar.classList.add('btn', 'btn-borrar');
            // Agregarlo al padre
            contenedorAcciones.appendChild(btnBorrar);

            // Agregarlo al <tr>
            nuevoContacto.appendChild(contenedorAcciones);

            // Agregarlo con los contactos
            listadoContactos.appendChild(nuevoContacto);

            // Resetear el formulario
            document.querySelector('form').reset();

            // Mostrar la notificación
            mostrarNotificacion('Contacto creado correctamente', 'correcto');

            // Actualizar el número
            numeroContactos();
        }
    }

    // Enviar los datos
    xhr.send(datos); 
}

// Actualiza el registro de la base de datos
function actualizarRegistro(datos) {
    // Crear el objeto
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Abrir la conexion
    xhr.open('POST', 'inc/modelos/modelo-contacto.php', true);
    // Leer la respuesta
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if(this.status === 200) {
            const respuesta = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(respuesta);
            
            if(respuesta.respuesta === 'correcto') {
                // Mostrar notificación de correcto
                mostrarNotificacion('Contacto editado correctamente', 'correcto');
            } else {
                // Mostrar notificación de error
                mostrarNotificacion('Hubo un error', 'error');
            }
            // Despues de tres segundos redireccionar
            setTimeout(() => {
                window.location.href = 'index.php';
            }, 3000);
        }
    }
    // Enviar la petición
    xhr.send(datos);
};

// Eliminar el contacto
function eliminarContacto(e) {
    if(e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('btn-borrar')) {
        // Toamr el ID
        const id = e.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-id');
        // Preguntar al usuario
        const confiramcion = confirm('¿Estás seguro (a)?');
        if(confiramcion) {
            // Llamado a ajax
            // Crear el objeto
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            // Abrir la conexion
            xhr.open('GET', `inc/modelos/modelo-contacto.php?id=${id}&accion=borrar`, true);
            // Leer la respuesta
            xhr.onload = function() {
                if(this.status === 200) {
                    const respuesta = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    
                    if(respuesta.respuesta === 'correcto') {
                        // Eliminar registro del DOM
                        e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
                        // Mostrar notificación
                        mostrarNotificacion('Contacto eliminado', 'correcto');
                        // Actualizar el número
                        numeroContactos();
                    } else {
                        // Mostrar notificación
                        mostrarNotificacion('Hubo un error', 'error');
                    }
                }
            }
            // Enviar la petición
            xhr.send();
        } 
        // console.log(id);
    }
    
}

// Notificación en pantalla
function mostrarNotificacion(mensaje, clase) {
    const notificacion = document.createElement('div');
    notificacion.classList.add(clase, 'notificacion', 'sombra');    
    notificacion.textContent = mensaje;
    const legend = document.querySelector('form legend');
    formularioContactos.insertBefore(notificacion, legend);
    setTimeout(() => {
        notificacion.classList.add('visible');
        setTimeout(() => {
            notificacion.classList.remove('visible');
            setTimeout(() => {
                notificacion.remove();
            }, 500);            
        }, 5000);
    }, 100);
}

// Buscador de registros
function buscarContactos(e) {
    // console.log(e.target.value);
    const expresion = new RegExp(e.target.value, "i"),
          registros = document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');
    
    registros.forEach(registro => {
        registro.style.display='none';
        if(registro.childNodes[1].textContent.replace(/\s/g, " ").search(expresion) != -1
        || registro.childNodes[3].textContent.replace(/\s/g, " ").search(expresion) != -1
        || registro.childNodes[5].textContent.replace(/\s/g, " ").search(expresion) != -1) {
            registro.style.display='table-row'
        }
        numeroContactos();
    });
};

// Muestra el número de contactos
function numeroContactos() {   
    const totalContactos = document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr'),
          contenedorNumero = document.querySelector('.total-contactos span');
    let total = 0;
    totalContactos.forEach(contacto => {
        if(contacto.style.display === '' || contacto.style.display === 'table-row') {
            contenedorNumero.textContent = ++total;
        }
    });
};
```